# thread 1 EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x101959bfc) Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

I try to update my project to Swift 3 and my app crash just after launching Xcode display the following message:

> thread 1 EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x101959bfc)

here's the line where the problem happened

```
var list:[PFObject]! = []
           (...)
let x = list[indexPath.row - 1]

let text:Int = (x["text"] as! NSArray)[0]  as! Int //The line where the error is displayed
```

The console only said that:

> (lldb)

I've removed all the breakpoints from the breakpoints navigator with no result, the issue happened both on device and on simulator. (I use Xcode 8.2)
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: It should print a stack dump before (lldb).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the stack trace printed right before `(lldb)`, and break down that statement in smaller pieces if is still hard to understand where the error actually is.

Considering the line the pointer is at, it could be that `x["text"]` is not an array, that the array is empty, or that the element is not an int.

In other words, those force unwrap could fail or the array could be empty.

Comment: How about when there is no trace?